# Will a Xbox gamertag transfer remove the account entry in billing.microsoft.com?

Tags: xbox, xbox-network

I have an issue with my Live ID account. It seems that I have a mismatch of countries in https://billing.microsoft.com for my Xbox Live account. So I need to remove my Xbox Live account (from billing.microsoft.com) and re-create a Xbox Live account.

I have been given the advice to transfer my gamertag to another Live ID account.
Now, the question is for you who has done a gamertag transfer:
Does a gamertag transfer actually remove the https://billing.microsoft.com account entry?
(You know, the 00000-00000-0nnnn-nnnnn account entry)

Answer (score 1):

No it does not, i created a new live id (chnage of email address) and transferred my gamertag to it (and the points moved as well).  I went to close the old windows live account but i could not as xbox live was connected to it.  So it does not transfer over as you would think it would.